# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - but don't even use 'length'!

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have read all over the web about this kind of error, and established it's not from having multiple jQuery core sources. I am using jQuery-1.10.2.min.js.

The page I am working on allows the user to select an Event from a list, after which the list of Activities belonging to that Event should be displayed on the page.

The jQuery/Ajax code reads:

```
$("#event").change(function ()
{
    //get the selected value
    var eventId = $(this).val();
    alert( "sel val is " +  eventId);//this works

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'stcg-json-responses.php?fct=getJSONAllActivitiesAtEvent',
        data: "eventId="+eventId,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
                alert("Data sent! " + eventId);//this works

                $.isArray(data.response)
                {
                    alert("this is an array");//this works
                    $.each(data.response, function (index, value)
                    {
                        // Loop through your results in jQuery and modify your HTML elements
                        htmlElement.append("<option id='key'>" + value + "</option>");
                    });
                }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error)
        {
            alert("Data not sent!");
            //console.log("Data not sent!");
        }
    });
```

Looking at the results with various browser dev tools, the Response is always fine - it is in the form of an anonymous array of JSON objects, each one comma-separated from the other. But the script above crashes on:
    $.each(data.response, function (index, value)

with the Uncaught TypeError.

To give you a better idea, the Response data is formatted as (for example):

```
[
{"activity_id":44,"activity_name":"Unknown activity","activity_desc":"Unknown activity","activity_short_code":"U","event_id":4,"capacity":0,"day_of_week":6,"date":"2012-03-24","project_leader":"","open":0},
{"activity_id":87,"activity_name":"Cleanup at Zoo Bellevue","activity_desc":"Zoo et parc d'accueil Bellevue","activity_short_code":"","event_id":4,"capacity":5,"day_of_week":6,"date":"2012-03-24","project_leader":"","open":0},
{"activity_id":89,"activity_name":"Ali Baba cleanup","activity_desc":"Ali Baba cleanup","activity_short_code":"","event_id":4,"capacity":10,"day_of_week":6,"date":"2012-03-24","project_leader":"","open":0}
]
```

Anyone have some idea what is going on here?
Thanks so much,
swissphp

P.S. Have tried with a plain Javascript for loop, but it crashes on array.length.

====================================================================================
SOLUTION - BASED ON HELP RECEIVED HERE, this is my new code, which works:

```
$("#event").change(function ()
{
    //get the selected value
    var eventId = $(this).val();

    var selectElement = $("#activity");

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'stcg-json-responses.php?fct=getJSONAllActivitiesAtEvent',
        data: "eventId="+eventId,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if ($.isArray(data))
            {
                $.each(data, function (index, value)
                {
                    // Loop through your results in jQuery and modify your HTML elements
                    selectElement.append($('<option></option>').val(index).html(value['activity_name']));
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error)
        { //etc etc etc
```

Many thanks to all who contributed!

Comment: `if ($.isArray(data.response))`

Comment: What is your variable htmlElement ? You try to append to something which not exists, maybe it's your fault ? And you don't test if data.response is an array.

Comment: **Note:** Ids must be unique, when you are appending it'll give the same id

Comment: i removed the htmlElement declaration in order to make this post easier to understand, but forgot to remove the rest. apologies. makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to call `$.each()` on `undefined`, which results in that error. From the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js):

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var value,
        i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj );
```

Or, in other words, `data.response` isn't defined in the JSON returned by your server. I suspect the problem is that you've missed out the `if` statement.

```
$.isArray(data.response)
{
    alert("this is an array");//this works
    $.each(data.response, function (index, value)
    {
        // Loop through your results in jQuery and modify your HTML elements
        htmlElement.append("<option id='key'>" + value + "</option>");
    });
}
```

That's a meaningless statement (`$.isArray(data.response)`) followed by an unconditional block of code. You likely meant:

```
if($.isArray(data.response))
{
    alert("this is an array");//this works
    $.each(data.response, function (index, value)
    {
        // Loop through your results in jQuery and modify your HTML elements
        htmlElement.append("<option id='key'>" + value + "</option>");
    });
}
```

Comment: I agree. I think your response is null at times. because your code works fine with proper data. http://jsfiddle.net/6ESMY/

Comment: aha! i misunderstood the use of $.isArray - now i see that it does NOTrecognize the returned data as an array.

Comment: Can you explain why, if it's NOT an array being returned, I can always see a Network Response value in the format [{data}, {data}, {data}] ?

Comment: @swissphp Ok, looking at the JSON in the question, it looks like you're misunderstanding what exactly is passed to the `success` callback function by jQuery. jQuery will automatically parse the response text as JSON, and (assuming it's valid and no parse error is thrown) pass the resulting object/array as the first argument of that function. That means in your case `data` **is** your array, there won't be a `response` property, so use `data` in place of `data.response`.

Comment: @anthony-grist, thanks so much! i was searching everywhere for what term would contain the data returned by JSON - couldn't find this answer anywhere till you told me. am posting my application of your help to my code, which now works, separately.